# Joomla K2 pages with malicious code

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I would like to ask for some help from You.

On my page I found that something inserts malicious code into the K2 pages, for example:

http://epicgenerator.net/index.php/gallery/season-1/season-1-fantasy

In the source code of /components/com_k2/templates/default/item.php it looks like this:

```
<!-- Item text -->
    <div class="itemFullText">
        <?php echo $this->item->introtext; ?>
    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="clr"></div>
```

And on my site it looks like this:

```
<div class="itemFullText">
        Here is the article
    </div>

<div class="clr"> <span style="position:absolute;left:-4800px;">Подробнее на сайте:  <!-- Document Starts --> <a href="https://samodelkick.ru" title="https://samodelkick.ru">https://samodelkick.ru</a><span></span><span></span><span></span><span><strong></strong></span><a href="https://dothouse.ru" title="https://dothouse.ru">https://dothouse.ru</a><ul><li></li><li></li></ul><!-- Final Section --><a href="https://svoidomsnulya.ru" title="https://svoidomsnulya.ru">https://svoidomsnulya.ru</a><span><strong></strong></span><b></b><b></b><a href="https://houserento.ru" title="https://houserento.ru">https://houserento.ru</a><!-- End Begin Block of DIV --> <span></span> <a href="https://stroikaudoma.ru" title="https://stroikaudoma.ru">https://stroikaudoma.ru</a><!-- Simple Comment --><!-- Comments are in the browser --><a href="https://fastumauto.ru" title="https://fastumauto.ru">https://fastumauto.ru</a><!-- IE Compatibility --> <span></span><span></span> <a href="https://remontvsvoidom.ru" title="https://remontvsvoidom.ru">https://remontvsvoidom.ru</a> <span></span> <i></i><a href="https://powerautoplus.ru" title="https://powerautoplus.ru">https://powerautoplus.ru</a><!-- .post-single --><strong></strong><strong></strong><a href="https://samodelkan.ru" title="https://samodelkan.ru">https://samodelkan.ru</a><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span> <!-- #menu-main --> <a href="https://domusremont.ru" title="https://domusremont.ru">https://domusremont.ru</a><strong></strong><strong></strong><!-- end #container --><a href="https://moidomremont.ru" title="https://moidomremont.ru">https://moidomremont.ru</a><!-- Final Section --><strong></strong><strong></strong><a href="https://avtoenter.ru" title="https://avtoenter.ru">https://avtoenter.ru</a><strong></strong><strong></strong><span></span><span></span><span></span><a href="https://houseunite.ru" title="https://houseunite.ru">https://houseunite.ru</a><!-- Ready page END. --><ul><li></li><li></li></ul><a href="https://medicinecu.ru" title="https://medicinecu.ru">https://medicinecu.ru</a><!-- Comments Are Editable --><i></i><em></em><i></i><a href="https://domstroiplus.ru" title="https://domstroiplus.ru">https://domstroiplus.ru</a> <!-- .ilovewp-page-intro --></span></div>
```

It's on all my K2 pages, the links change, so it should be some kind of Javascript.

Tried on different browsers, and different machines, same result.

Any idea what inserts the code into K2?

Comment: It sounds like malware somewhere on the site, perhaps generating the links on page load or pulling them from a remote source. If you have a clean backup you can do a diff check or else try a malware scanner, either a Joomla specific one or a general PHP one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe attacker can accessed your site or at least with publisher permission.
So

- Check all content and make sure no injection around
- Check all files and make sure no injection around ( It would be nightmare if attacker can access your physical server )
- Change all passwords
- Check and patch all server securities

Finally check your site is upgraded, also with server.
And yay, make sure you didn't give your access in a night with tons of alcohol :p

Comment: Content is checked. Noone accessed the site.
Joomla is patched.

Only thing missing is the "check all files". I don't know where to check? What can possibly insert that kinda rubbish inside a div?

I have checked everything that can preg_replace,  and is loaded on that page, but nothing.

I clearly cannot find what inserts that code?